# How do I use Extreme Value Theorem and uniform continuity to prove this question?

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-continuity

[image]

I'm stuck on both parts of this question. Can somebody help me here?

Comment: I don't understand the condition.  It starts "for $a,b\in [x_0,x_1]\dots$ but then the condition has nothing to do with $a$ or $b$.

Comment: That's what I'm not getting either :( This is just how the question is posted in my book.

Comment: I think it's a typo and that they meant ot say "for $a,b\in [x_0,x_1]$, we have that $|f(a)-f(b)|<\epsilon_0$.  Otherwise the statement isn't even true.